# FullCalendar not displaying time from JSON events when allday is false

Tags: php, json, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar and populate the calendar from an ajax call.

But I can not get the times to display if the allday is set to false

I was looking at [FullCalendar not displaying time from JSON events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860532/fullcalendar-not-displaying-time-from-json-events) but did not seem to help.

This is the JSON I am sending back:

> ][{"id":"18","title":"r2222","start":"2012-10-02
>   08:00:00","end":"2012-10-02
>   11:00:00","textColor":"#000000","allday":false,"color":"#ffffff"},
>
> {"id":"1","title":"Test
>   123","start":"2012-10-16","end":null,"textColor":"#000000","allday":false,"color":"#ffffff"},
>
> {"id":"16","title":"happy
>   gallown","start":"2012-10-31","end":"2012-10-31","textColor":"#fffcfc","allday":true,"color":"#d92727"},
>
> {"id":"17","title":"recur","start":"2012-10-03
>   19:00:00","end":"2012-10-03
>   21:00:00","textColor":"#000000","allday":false,"color":"#ff56ff"}]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`allDay` is case sensitive; change it from `allday` to `allDay` - I just spent 25 minutes myself hunting this one down.

Answer (score -1):

You can follow this `allday` to `allDay` and Time should be start: `2010-01-09T12:30:00` need to add `T` between date and time .

```
events: [
    {
        title  : 'event1',
        start  : '2010-01-01'
    },
    {
        title  : 'event2',
        start  : '2010-01-05',
        end    : '2010-01-07'
    },
    {
        title  : 'event3',
        start  : '2010-01-09T12:30:00',
        allDay : false // will make the time show
    }
]
```

Comment: Note that the formatted date and time is ISO8601 compliant and FullCalendar leverages MomentJS that works great with ISO8601 dates. From PHP you can return this format using `$dateTime->format(DateTime::ISO8601)`.