# fullcalendar event not working

Tags: php, javascript, json, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar to display events and I used JSON for the events and get the json object form another page but when ever I treid I get this `500 Internal Server Error` I found a queston in stackoverflow and used their code
[FullCalendar not displaying time from JSON events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860532/fullcalendar-not-displaying-time-from-json-events#_=_)

This my Javascript code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({                                 
            editable: false,
           events:'/json.php'
        });
    });

</script>
```

PHP code:

```
$sql="
SELECT
    t.trans_id
    , r.res_name
    , l.location_name
    , to_char( t.trans_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy' )
    , s.ts_from
    , s.ts_to
    , t.booked_units
    , t.max_value
    , t.remaining
FROM
    tsm_transaction_tbl t
    , tsm_location_tbl l
    , tsm_resource_tbl r
    , tsm_timeslot_tbl s
WHERE
    t.location_id = l.location_id
    AND t.resource_id = r.res_id
    AND t.ts_id = s.ts_id
";

$parse=oci_parse($conn,$sql);
oci_execute($parse);
$events = array();
while($row=oci_fetch_array($parse))
{
    $start = $row[3];
    $end = $row[3];
    $title = $row[1];
    $eventsArray['id'] =  $row[0];
    $eventsArray['title'] = $title;
    $eventsArray['start'] = $start . " " . $row[4];
    $eventsArray['end'] = $end;
    $eventsArray['allDay'] = false;
    $events[] = $eventsArray;
}
oci_close($conn);
echo json_encode($events);
```

Comment: "500 Internal Server Error" is not in relation with your fullcalendar problem, so it's a server problem. Please add information of your webserver logfiles to your post.

Comment: thank you for reply I found the problem it was json_encode not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `json_encode` then I used `Zend_Json::encode` It is Zend class that generated the JSON object

```
<?php
require_once('Json.php');

$sql="select t.trans_id,r.res_name,l.location_name,to_char(t.trans_date,'mm/dd/yyyy'),s.ts_from,s.ts_to,t.booked_units,t.max_value,t.remaining
from tsm_transaction_tbl t,tsm_location_tbl l,tsm_resource_tbl r,tsm_timeslot_tbl s
where t.location_id=l.location_id and t.resource_id=r.res_id and t.ts_id=s.ts_id";
$parse=oci_parse($conn,$sql);
oci_execute($parse);
$events = array();
while($row=oci_fetch_array($parse))
{
    $start = $row[3];
    $end = $row[3];
    $title = $row[1];

    $eventsArray['id'] =  $row[0];
    $eventsArray['title'] = $title;
    $eventsArray['start'] = $start." ".$row[4].":00:00";
    $eventsArray['end'] = $end." ".$row[5].":00:00";
    $eventsArray['allDay'] = false;
    $eventsArray['description']="Timeslot: ".$row[4]."-".$row[5]."<br> Location: ".$row[2]."<br> Max value: ".$row[7]."<br>Booked units: ".$row[6]."<br> Remaining: ".$row[8];
    $events[] = $eventsArray;
}
oci_close($conn);

echo Zend_Json::encode($events);

?>
```